# Connecting BigQuery to Dataproc Metastore/hive tables

Tags: google-bigquery, hive-metastore, google-cloud-dataproc-metastore

Is it possible to connect `bigquery` to `hive/dataproce metastore` database? I don't want to load hive tables(orc or parquet) into bigquery internal storage. If bigquery can route its sql to hive and then hive runs query on spark that works. I considered using `Hive CLI` instead of bigquery to execute queries but being able to do it via bigquery will allow unified interface to execute ad-hoc sqls. I also considered external tables in big query which can directly points to raw `parquet/orc` locations. However orc tables are also ACID tables managed by hive so bigquery directly accessing raw Orc dataset may result in inconsistent reads.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect Hive/Dataproc to BigQuery or vice versa by using Spark BigQuery Connector. Take note that SparkSQL supports Hive and not BigQuery even though BigQuery reads and writes using spark-bigquery-connector.

Comment: it seems `Spark BigQuery Connector` is for spar/dataproc to read and possibly write to bigquery but not other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by using `Biglake` metastore catalog. I stumble upon this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/iceberg-tables#create-using-biglake-metastore) as I was also looking to expose `apache iceberg` external tables to bigquery. It seems you can use same catalog to export Hive (or dataproc metastore) tables to bigquery as well.